# Is XMPP good choice for this solution?

Tags: xmpp

I want to build communication solution for my project. Thinking about not to develop everything from scratch, but to use XMPP servers.

My project consist of many "mini-servers" (based on raspberry pi) scattered around different locations. Every mini-server should be reachable for mobile applications on its own network, this network could be isolated from internet. Every "mini-server" has to be autonomous and be able to live without internet, autethicate its own mobile client and respond to their requests. So mini-servers could be on private offline networks, could be on known static or unknown dynamic IP addresses behind firewalls.

Some mini-server users want theirs mini-servers to be reachable from the internet. So there is one more, let's call it cloud. This cloud would be responsible for routing request from mobile clients from the internet to their mini-servers.

My idea was to use XMPP server on every mini-server, my application would log in to this server on localhost and create chatroom. Every mobile client would connect to xmpp server and chat with my application request-response. When mini-server owner wants to connect to the interet to be reachable from outside, I would just reconfigure xmpp server to connect to my cloud XMPP cluster (on known public domain) and mobile app to connect to this public cloud server if not on private network. Every mini-server will have its own users, managed by other app on it. Mini-server has also log, this could be written for example to another chatroom. Mini-servers or mobile users does not want to talk to each other. It is pure mobile user to mini-server request-response realtime communication.

Can cloud-XMPP servers route request to mini-server xmpp server?

Is this possible with XMPP? Is it good use? Some better ideas?

Comment: In the end I ended up using own solution on WebSockets and binary messages serialized using protobuf. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe looks like XMPP server-to-server federation, with some local Raspberry PI XMPP domains and some other XMPP servers on the internet.

So, I think yes, what you would like to achieve is doable with XMPP server.
A server like [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im) works very well on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Is it ok that mini-servers are dynamic ip, without dns? In xmpp docs is everywhere stated that user id should have "domain identifier". Every mini-server has its own set of users.

Comment: No, you need DNS names for those servers. This will be required for routing to proper JID.

Comment: So XMPP is unusable for me, unless I make some DNS for every mini-server (not really a solution for me)? I hoped that there is some way to route messages to mini-server not by domain name, but by some server-name or id. So if server1105 is connected to cloud cluster, cloud servers know about it, if message is sent to admin@server1105 they will redirect this message over open socket to this server. If this server is not connected to cloud cluster, it could not be delivered.